# How do I run tagged Feature/scenario/Examples in Webdriverio-cucumber/boilerplate?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, webdriver.io

Hi _ if anyone can help here- I am trying to run a specific scenario with examples by using Cucumber tags- this is the expression I am using to run the tests built with Webdriver- Cucumber-boilerplate framework-

npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@sanity and @stage'

When I use the above, nothing happens - i have defined the tag - '@Tag' at the feature level- so am expecting that all the scenarios within the feature file will get executed, however when i run the above command- nothing happens. Can someone please help?

npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@Tag

```
    Example:
    @sanity
    Feature: ICRM test
        As a user, I want to login with test website
        Scenario: login with credentials
            Given I open the url "<Link>"
            Then I expect that the title is "iCRM Login"
            When I set "<Username>" to the inputfield "#loginEmail"
            And  I click on the button "[role=button]"
            And  I set "<Password>" to the inputfield "#Password1"
            Then I click on the button "//button[contains(text(),'Log In')]"
            Then I wait on element "//body/div[@id='wrap']/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]" for 10000ms to be displayed
            @stage
            Examples:
                | Username                        | Password | Link                                             |
                | sameer.joshi@test.com | test5# | https://test.com/icrm/index.html |
            @Live
        Examples:
           | Username                        | Password | Link                                             |
            | sameer.joshi@test.com | Virtua5# | https://testlinkslive.com/icrm/index.html 

|
```

Comment: Can you please edit your description? Looks like same thing is repeated with slight change in tag. It's a bit confusing as to what you're asking.

Comment: @IAmMilinPatel updated Question sir.